# Explicit formula for embedding of real projective spaces into Euclidean spaces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, differential-topology, embeddings, projective-varieties

I am interested in representing vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a sign-invariant and efficient manner. That is, I am looking for a function
$$f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$$
such that for $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ it holds that
$$f(v)=f(-v)$$
and $f(v)$ does not cause a loss of information, except about the sign. Based on my research, the best approach to do so is to consider $v$ as a tuple $(c,\xi)$ with $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\xi\in\mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{R})$, so that $c$ decodes the length of $v$ and $\xi$ its orientation in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

I am interested in implementing this numerically. Representing $c$ is trivial, but representing $\xi$ is not. My current understanding is that the Whitney theorem provides the theoretical basis for a lower bound on $d$. I want $d$ to be as small as possible, while the computation effort to compute $f(v)$ should at the same time not be excessive.

This answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505639/explicit-formula-for-embedding-projective-spaces-into-euclidean-space) provides an explicit formula (using all products  $v_iv_j$ where $i\le j$) with $d=1+\frac{1}{2}n(n+3)$ and this paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926224508000661) claims to have an explicit formula with $d=\frac{1}{2}n(n+3)$. As far as I understand, the Whitney theorem proves that it is possible to represent $\xi$ with roughly $2n$ dimensions. Also, it appears to me that there was a enormous amount of work in the second half of the 20th century to find low values of $d$ for all sorts of $n$.

However, I didn't quite manage to find a good survey on explicit methods to compute these embeddings. So my question is the following:

**Does an explicit embedding of $\mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{R})$ for arbitrary $n\ge 1$ exist, which embeds into $\mathbb{R}^l$ with $l$ being an affine function of $n$?**

Edit: $f$ shall furthermore be continuous.

Comment: I think no linearly-sized subset of that explicit formula will work, and I doubt any other linearly-sized formula can do better.

Comment: @Matt F. What is intuition behind the claim that no linearly-sized formula can do better?  Results from the literature suggest that such functions must exist. So I'd assume it's just about how complex is it to compute it, no? Actually, this afternoon I did manage to find a function that satisfied the above requirements. It's basically a an extension of Euler angles to n-dimensional spaces. However, it's the function is not continuous, so I guess it's not a contradiction to what I wrote before. I added the requirement for continuity though.

Comment: I think you want to take c not in R, but in the tautological line bundle... Or are you taking oriented projective space?

Comment: To me it is unclear what your goal is. If you want to represent vectors "up to sign" then just pick an orthant and normalize. I.e. if $v_1 < 0$ then $f(v) = -v$ and if $v_1 > 0$ then $f(v) = v$. The case $v_1 = 0$ gives the same problem in dimension one lower which you can solve with $v_2 < 0$ resp. $v_2 >0$ etc up to $v_n$.

Comment: @VítTuček that's true. My edit surely rules out your suggestion though. I require $f$ to be continuous. This is not the case for your proposition.

Comment: It is probably useful to retain the symmetries of the projective space when you embed. So my guess is that the embedding you saw, with $v_iv_j$, is the smart one to use.

Comment: @MattF. The proof of Whitney's theorem shows that $2n+1$ generic linear combinations of the $v_i v_j$ should work, and it would be fun to find a concrete linear combination with this property. But I agree with Ben McKay; I don't think there is a practical benefit in squeezing down from $\binom{n+1}{2}$ to $2n+1$.

Comment: If $2n+1$ is really enough then maybe it will work to use the $n+1$ squares $v_i^2$ with $0\le i\le n$ and the $n$ cyclic expressions $w_j=\sum_{i=0}^n v_iv_{i+j}$ with $1\le j\le n$.

Comment: @MattF. That's not a good idea for two reasons. (1) $j$ and $n+1-j$ give the same sum, so that's redundant and (2) $\sum v_i^2 = 1$, so using all the $v_i$ is redundant.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer It should be sufficient to just pick the linear combinations randomly, no?

Comment: Right. (That's what the word "generic" was doing in my comment.)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Do you have a reference to a paper/book/etc. that explains that $2n+1$ linear combinations of $v_iv_j$ suffice? I didn't look into this issue for some months, but would like to get back to it.

Comment: Look at pretty much any proof of the Whitney embedding theorem, for example, the one in these notes http://www.cse.lehigh.edu/~sxie/lecture_notes/diff_manifolds/lecture10.pdf . If $M$ is a smooth compact $n$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $\phi : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ is a generic linear map, then $\phi$ restricts to a closed embedding $M \to \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer thank you very much! I'm an engineer really, so it's sometimes a bit hard for me to find these things.